# Help with a Nest E install on a old HVAC system

Tags: hvac, thermostat, nest

Hello I am trying to replace this thermostat with a Nest E but this has proven more complicated than I thought:
[image: Old Thermostat Front]

[image: Old Thermostat Back]

I plugged all the cables to the nest adapter and figured that the blue wire which wasn't used on the old setup is the common wire so I plugged that in the C position for the plate and on the furnace side I added it to a pigtail that had the R wire on it. After charging it, it turns out that it cannot detect any power from the R wire but 24V is detected on the C wire. Since I wasn't making any headway I rewired the old thermostat and that works fine so I do not think I've burnt out anything. I am not sure where to go from there so any help is appreciated. Here are the pictures from the furnace side:
[image: Furnace wiring diagram]

[image: Thermostat wiring furnace side]

[image: Furnace wiring]

Comment: Great pictures!  That wiring diagram looks like something a future civilization would find after our world is in ruin.  Great patina on the inside of your blower...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Somebody misplaced the blue wire from the system to the thermostat

It appears that the previous installer, for some bizarre reason, connected the blue wire *and* the red wire in the cable from the indoor unit to the thermostat to the fat red R wire coming from the indoor unit.  Luckily, between the wiring diagram on your unit showing the fat brown wire as the indoor unit's C wire, and the fact we can trace the air conditioner control from the Y wire from the thermostat, to the red wire in a cable, with only a white wire returning to join up with that brown C wire, means that we can simply swing the blue wire from the thermostat over to join with the other wires connected to the fat brown C wire and put a replacement wirenut on the junction of the red R wires in order to get everything in order for your Nest to work.

Comment: We are in business! Thanks for the help!